# Find Capitalized Text and make it Bold

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, cap

I'm hoping for a macro code that will work on WORD 2003. I have text like the following:

> THIS IS THE BEGINNING of a sentence that continues on from here.

I'd like to make the capitalized text bold:

> **THIS IS THE BEGINNING** of a sentence that continues on from here.

I understand that this would be trivial if the bold text were text-formatted as "AllCaps" but it is not. It was created using caps lock.

Any ideas? I can get it going, but I can't figure out how to add a complex find and replace within the VBA code.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which [Word provides](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx) in the advanced section of its Find functionality.

Here's a quick sample:

```
Public Sub Test()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "<[A-Z]{1,}>"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

"<[A-Z]{1,}>" means the following:

- "<" means match starting at the beginning of a word
- "[]" means match one of the characters inside the brackets
- "[A-Z]" the A-Z part, when inside the brackets, means the uppercase letters A through Z
- "{1,}" means match the preceding at least once (in this case, an uppercase letter must occur at least once in a row)
- ">" means the match must end at the end of a word.  The pattern would not match, for example "THIs" because the uppercase letters do not go to the end of the word.

One caveat you have to deal with is single-letter words - I and A will be bolded with this pattern scheme.  You may find it easier to create a pattern that matches whole groups of uppercase words, but you will still have to find a way to deal with leading or trailing uppercase, single-letter words.

If you have questions, leave a comment and I can try to explain further.